# remoteControlReceivedWithEvent Never called

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio-streaming, avplayer

I'm trying to allow a remote or earbuds to play and pause audio when the app is in background or the screen is locked.  So In viewDidLoad I have:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

I then have:

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {



if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {



switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {



    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:

        [self playOrStop];

        break;



    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:


        break;



    case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:


        break;



    default:

        break;

}

}


}
```

But, it never gets called.  Running in background is turned on, the AVSession is set in AppDelegate.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Never found anything at all.  I can get it sometimes to stop it, but it ends up restarting after every phone call is hung up.  Very annoying.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but an alternative is to use the newer [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPRemoteCommandCenter_Ref/index.html) APIs instead if you're targeting iOS 7.1+

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to add:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Any subclass of `UIResponder` needs to implement this, or it won't accept first responder status.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it does work, as that was the OS version I started using remote controls with.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

in viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated instead of viewDidLoad.